# How to use Yelp api v3 in swift

Tags: swift, yelp

So long story short I want to be able to get reviews, images, etc. about locations and add them to a map. Using Yelp's api v3 seemed to be the best way to do this but i'm having trouble finding decent/updated/working documentation.

I looked here:
https://github.com/codepath/ios_yelp_swift/tree/master/Yelp

but it is outdated(both version of api and swift)

I did manage to find this updated doc. on v3:
https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/tree/master/fusion/swift

but the code doesn't work.

I also looked through just about ever question/thread on here about yelp's api but most question are outdated or never answered.

But from my understanding of looking through other questions, in order to use the api I have to create a HTTP GET request, change authorization, and decode the data with the url: https://api.yelp.com/v3 (but with my desired terms and such) but the documentation yelp provides doesn't include any of that?

My question is, can anyone provide a full example (or link) of using the v3 api in swift properly or provide some clarity about how to use it?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a bit of hacking around to get it.

```
    fileprivate func fetchYelpBusinesses(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        let apikey = "YourAPIKey"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?latitude=\(latitude)&longitude=\(longitude)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(apikey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                print(">>>>>", json, #line, "<<<<<<<<<")
            } catch {
                print("caught")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that wants to use Yelp's api but is struggling to find proper documentation, I found that instead of using 'yelpapi' pod you can install 'CDYelpFusionKit'. It has a lot more documentation and is easier to use.

Link to documentation: https://github.com/chrisdhaan/CDYelpFusionKit